# How to use google.script.run to call a server side function on drop down change? (Google Docs)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-workspace

I am working on a way auto-populate my google docs using google apps scripting. I want to populate a dropdown in a sidebar with a column from my google sheet, then fetch this on the server side when it changes.

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('FCAR')
      .addItem('Select Class', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXX").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  console.log(sheet.getLastColumn());
  var classes = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < sheet.getLastColumn()-1; i++) {
    classes.push(data[i][0]);
  }
  console.log(classes);

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput();
  html.append(generateHtml(classes));
  console.log(html.getContent())
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

// Function to generate HTML string for the dropdown
function generateHtml(options) {
    var dropdownHTML = '<base target="_top">';
    dropdownHTML += '<select id="myDropdown" onchange="dropdownChanged(this)">';
    options.forEach(function(option) {
        dropdownHTML += '<option value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>';
    });
    dropdownHTML += '</select>';

    // Add client-side JavaScript function
    dropdownHTML += '<script>';
    dropdownHTML += 'function dropdownChanged(dropdown) {';
    dropdownHTML += 'var selectedValue = dropdown.value;';
    dropdownHTML += 'alert("Selected value: " + selectedValue);';
    dropdownHTML += 'google.script.run.doSomething(selectedValue);'; // Call server-side function
    dropdownHTML += '}';
    dropdownHTML += '</script>';

    return dropdownHTML;
}


// Function to handle dropdown change event
function doSomething(value) {
      // Get the active Google Document
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  
  // Get the header of the document
  var header = doc.getHeader();
  
  // Set the text of the header to the selected value
  header.appendParagraph(value);
}
```

The drop down is populated successfully, and when I change it, I get the alert of the new value, but doSomething does not execute or give any error.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

About `The drop down is populated successfully, and when I change it, I get the alert of the new value, but doSomething does not execute or give any error.`, it seems that `doSomething` is not used in your script. And at `google.script.run.dropdownChanged(selectedValue);`, the function `dropdownChanged` is tried to be run in the Google Apps Script side. I guess that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, how about modifying it to `doSomething`? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
dropdownHTML += 'google.script.run.dropdownChanged(selectedValue);';
```

#### To:

```
dropdownHTML += 'google.script.run.doSomething(selectedValue);';
```

By this, the function `doSomething` at the Google Apps Script is run with a value of `selectedValue`.

#### Note:

- If the 1st page header is enabled, please disable it and test it again. Because I'm worried that your `doSomething` might not be able to put the value to the 1st page header. Please be careful about this.

### Added 1:

From your following reply,

> it seems through my many revisions I forgot to change this. After calling the correct function as you suggested there is still no change in the header.

Although I'm not sure about your actual Google Document, I'm worried about "Note" section in my answer. If you are required to enable the 1st page header, please modify your function `doSomething` as follows. By this, `appendParagraph(value)` is run on both the 1st page header and other pages.

```js
function doSomething(value) {
  // Get the active Google Document
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  // I modified the below script.
  const document = doc.getBody().getParent();
  let s = null;
  while (s = document.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.HEADER_SECTION, s)) {
    s.getElement().asHeaderSection().appendParagraph(value);
  }
}
```

### Added 2:

From your following reply,

> My current google document is a completely blank document

In this case, please modify `doSomething` as follows.

```js
function doSomething(value) {
      // Get the active Google Document
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  
  // Get the header of the document
  var header = doc.getHeader() || doc.addHeader();
  
  // Set the text of the header to the selected value
  header.appendParagraph(value);
}
```

In the case of new Document, no header is existing as the default. So, it is required to use `addHeader`.

### Added 3:

From your following reply,

> I am seeing errors on the doSomething() call in this Executions tab. I cannot seem to get any information from these other than they failed though.

> However it is worth noting that I have not been able to get an error to show from doSomething in the last hour.

I think that you can see the error message in "Executions" of the script editor. But, I'm worried that you might not be able to understand this. So, please modify the function `doSomething` as follows. By this, when an error occurs at `doSomething`, the error message is shown in the dialog.

```js
function doSomething(value) {
  try {
    // Get the active Google Document
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

    // Get the header of the document
    var header = doc.getHeader() || doc.addHeader();

    // Set the text of the header to the selected value
    header.appendParagraph(value);

  } catch (e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(e.stack), "sample");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems through my many revisions I forgot to change this. After calling the correct function as you suggested there is still no change in the header.

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. About `Sorry, it seems through my many revisions I forgot to change this. After calling the correct function as you suggested there is still no change in the header.`, can you confirm "Note" section in my answer? If that is not useful, can you provide your Google Document? Because I think that in this case, it is required to correctly replicate your situation. By the way, when I tested the script reflected my proposed modification, unfortunately, the value is added to the header row. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It is hopeful it was working on your end. By first page header, do you mean the option for a different header to the first page? If so, that is already disabled. Forgive me for being new to stack overflow, but how should I provide the google document?

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. About `By first page header, do you mean the option for a different header to the first page? If so, that is already disabled.`, in this case, I think that `appendParagraph(value)` works and you can see the value to the header. But, you say `there is still no change in the header`. From this, I added one more modification point in my answer. Please confirm it. If that doesn't resolve it, in that case, I think that it is required to test your situation using your sample Document by correctly replicating it. First, please test my added modification.

Comment: I just tested with your suggested change and still no result in the header. My current google document is a completely blank document, and no header is being populated. Could this at all be an issue with the organization my account is associated with?

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. From `My current google document is a completely blank document` in your reply, I could understand the reason for your current issue. So, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it. It is considered that the reason for your current issue was due to no header.

Comment: I appreciate all your help. Unfortunately that solution still is not working for me, as the document remains empty after I change the dropdown selection.

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. About `I appreciate all your help. Unfortunately, that solution still is not working for me, as the document remains empty after I change the dropdown selection.`, in this case, I think that it is required to test it using your Google Document. Please provide your Google Document including your current script for testing it. By this, I would like to test it. From `My current google document is a completely blank document`, I understood that your document has no text.

Comment: Okay, here is the link to my document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ns49sYRuWbrYFCuP3MEj1btm9KEDlE-_r0XAUCEdg4k/edit?usp=sharing I believe you should be able to access the script from here.

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot open it. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: I have updated the access, my apologies. Here is the link again: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ns49sYRuWbrYFCuP3MEj1btm9KEDlE-_r0XAUCEdg4k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. I could open it. In this case, I have no permission to read your Spreadsheet. So, when I tested your current script by changing the Spreadsheet ID to my one, and when `showSidebar` is run and select one of the texts, I can see the value is added to the header. It seems that the proposed script works. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating `Unfortunately that solution still is not working for me`?

Comment: Sure I can be as detailed as possible. I will start from exiting my document:
1. Open the document
2. Select the FCAR Menu
3. Select "Select Class"
4. In the Apps Script Application sidebar, select any different dropdown option
5. No change

The script is quite simple, so it is a bit hard to provide more details than this.

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. From your reply, can you provide your Spreadsheet? I'm worried that the reason for your current issue might be due to the values from Spreadsheet. Because when I tested your current script using sample values, the script worked correctly.

Comment: Sure. Here is the link to the sheet. It is extremely simple at the moment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rAuREWGBXI7YEFaEa10B7G2GAPsCwj7lWW8GJ9HB1tY/edit?usp=sharing

As I mentioned too, populating the values of the dropdown with the first column of this sheet seems successful as the value is returned in the alert on my end. My script just doesn't reach back to the server side.

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. When I tested your current script using your provided Spreadsheet, I can see the selected value in the header. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `Unfortunately that solution still is not working for me`. Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, for example, when you can see the text in the dropdown list, when you check the error message at "Executions" on the script editor after you select one of the texts, can you see an error?

Comment: @William Martell Or, about `As I mentioned too, populating the values of the dropdown with the first column of this sheet seems successful as the value is returned in the alert on my end.`, when I saw your current script, it seems that `alert` is not used. Can you confirm whether you are using the correct current Google Document and the current script?

Comment: Let me check the error at Executions and see if anything is there. I did remove the alert recently just to check if my code changes were being updated correctly.

Comment: I am seeing errors on the doSomething() call in this Executions tab. I cannot seem to get any information from these other than they failed though.

Comment: However it is worth noting that I have not been able to get an error to show from doSomething in the last hour.

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. About `I am seeing errors on the doSomething() call in this Executions tab. I cannot seem to get any information from these other than they failed though.`, I think that an error message can be seen at "Executions" of the script editor. By this, when an error occurs at `doSomething`, the error message is shown in the dialog. So, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it and test it again.

Comment: I just tried this. In the executions tab, doSomething() is still reported as failed, but there is no dialog showing with the error message.

Comment: I have located the specific error just now. It seems that there is some authorization error. I changed my code to run with an error handler and now I can see the error: ScriptError: Authorization is required to perform that action. I am now sure what to do here as this is a bound script and I am using the same account to script and host the doc.

Comment: @William Martell Thank you for replying. About `there is some authorization error. I changed my code to run with an error handler and now I can see the error: ScriptError: Authorization is required to perform that action.`, I understood that you have never authorized scopes. So, please authorize. When you don't authorize, the script is not correctly run. For example, when you directly run `onOpen` with the script editor, you can see the dialog. Please authorize the scopes. You can see it at the official document. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization